# How filter by url in django rest framework

Tags: django, url, django-rest-framework, django-views

VIEWS

```
class PageView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = postserializer
    # queryset = Page.objects.all()
    def get_queryset(self,request,*args,**kwargs,):
        queryset = Page.objects.all()
        return Page.objects.filter(event=self.kwargs['author'])
```

URLS

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('^author/(?P<author>.+)/$', PageView ,basename="author")
router.register(r'authors',views.AuthorView, basename="authors")

urlpatterns = [

    path("", include(router.urls))
]
```

Model

```
class Page(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    post = models.TextField()
```

how to search for particular authors of my post
like
/author/bob/

i've been trying to follow offical documentation but its unclear to me :\
http://www.tomchristie.com/rest-framework-2-docs/api-guide/filtering

Comment: welcome to SO! Are you running into an error with the `PageView` class? If so, please post it here.

Comment: @abhivemp
404 error not found

Comment: You spelled class wrong in your views (missing the 'c')

Comment: @abhivemp bad paste  :D

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, you are not searching for and using the `queryset` function correctly. I believe this should do the fix.

```
def queryset(self):
   postAuthor = self.kwargs['author']
   return Page.objects.filter(postAuthor)
```

See if that works.

Comment: Still? That means the query is wrong. Alternatively, your `urls.py` file may be misconfigured

Comment: @Abey you also need to import your views for Page view to work in the URL like so: `views.PageView`